# Why does this happen to my out of bounds shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm importing a PSD file into Illustrator and I've noticed there's sort of a "clipping shape" the size of the artboard mixed with the shapes that happen to be "out of bounds" (in this case, the circle):
[image]

When I move the shape, it's clear that it's being clipped to that artboard-sized rectangle.
[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to remove that clipping shape outside of deleting it (it deletes the circular shape as well). I can't "undo" the clipping mask because it doesn't show it as a clipping mask, it just shows it as if it were a singular object. The only way to remove the artboard-sized object is to expand the object but by doing so I'm permanently cropping the circle, which I don't want because I need the whole circle for other things.

Comment: Direct Selection Tool (white arrow), hold down the option/alt key and then click *just* the rectangle - you should *only* see the rectangle highlight, not the circle - then delete. Does that work?

Comment: @Scott it worked! Thanks so much. I feel so stupid now ahh